# How to change Markdown link relative path as preprocessing of gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: markdown, gatsby, remarkjs

I am developping a static blog using Gatsby.
It use `gatsby-transformer-remark` and `gatsby-plugin-i18n` plugin to support multiple languages.

I am managing the articles in the GitHub repository as follows.

- /blog

  - /2017

    - /06

      - 01-foo.en.md
      - 01-foo.zh.md
    - /09

      - 01-bar.en.md
      - 01-bar.zh.md

And links between the articles is necessary. Therefore, in order not to become a dead link when looking at GitHub with a Web browser, we set up a link as follows.

```
[link](/blog/2017/09/01-bar.en.md)
```

However, this has the problem of dead linking when displayed using Gatsby.
Because the URL in the actually generated browser is as follows.

```
/[gatsby-config.pathPrefix]/en/blog/2017/09/01-bar
```

So, when I run `gatsby build` or `gatsby develop`, I want to replace links between articles using regular-expressions, as preprocessing to analyze Markdown by `gatsby-transformer-remark`.

How can I do the above?

---

*Added: Feb, 2*

I also tried relative links.

```
[link](../09/01-bar)
```

But the URL is `/[gatsby-config.pathPrefix]/en/blog/2017/06/09/01-bar`, which is dead link.
Because Gatsby makes HTML place to `/[gatsby-config.pathPrefix]/en/blog/2017/06/09/01-bar/index.html`.

So I added `../` once more. And it worked. However, this has some problems.

- I can not navigate from Markdown in GitHub to another Markdown. Because the relative path is different.
- In addition, it cannot navigate without adding language suffix (e.g. `01-bar.en.md`), but when I add it, Gatsby cannot be recognized this time and 404 or raw Markdown are displayed.

Comment: If you use relative URLs then they should work from anywhere.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work.
I added its details, so please see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [create a plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/remark-plugin-tutorial/) for [gatsby-transformer-remark](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark)

`plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-linker/index.js`:

```
const visit = require('unist-util-visit');
module.exports = ({ markdownAST }) => {
  visit(markdownAST, 'link', node => {
    if (
      node.url &&
      !node.url.startsWith('//') &&
      !node.url.startsWith('http') &&
      node.url.startsWith('/')
    ) {
      node.url = node.url.replace(/(.*)\.(\w{2}).md(#.*)?$/, (match, base, language, hash) => {
        return `/${language}${base}${hash}`
      })
    }
  });

  return markdownAST;
};
```

`plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-linker/package.json`:

```
{}
```

`./gatsby-config.js`:

```
{
...
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
    options: {
      plugins: [
        ...
        'gatsby-remark-relative-linker',
      ],
    }
  }
},
```

Here I am removing the `.md` from the urls and prefixing the language.
Keep your urls as in markdown starting with `/` like `[text](/blog/2017/09/01-bar.en.md)`

Comment: Great! I could not idea of using a local plugin.