# In Gatsby project with gatsby-transformer-remark, how to change Markdown link from folder1/filename.md to /folder1/filename/?

Tags: markdown, gatsby, remarkjs

In this [Gatsby project](https://github.com/stephane-klein/gatsby-remark-convert-linker-from-md-to-html-example), I use [`gatsby-transformer-remark`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark) to transform Markdown pages to html.

I have this [issue](https://github.com/stephane-klein/gatsby-remark-convert-linker-from-md-to-html-example/issues/1).

Question: How can I configure `gatsby-transformer-remark` to rename all `*.md` link to `*/`?

I think I need to explore [How to change Markdown link relative path as preprocessing of gatsby-transformer-remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553146/how-to-change-markdown-link-relative-path-as-preprocessing-of-gatsby-transformer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Markdown link relative path as preprocessing of gatsby-transformer-remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553146/how-to-change-markdown-link-relative-path-as-preprocessing-of-gatsby-transformer)

Answer (score 1):

I have find a solution: https://github.com/stephane-klein/gatsby-remark-convert-linker-from-md-to-html-example/commit/a941cf990be4a16c72c46e3c893f37509a3e5890

In [`plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-linker/index.js`](https://github.com/stephane-klein/gatsby-remark-convert-linker-from-md-to-html-example/blob/master/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-linker/index.js):

```
const visit = require('unist-util-visit');
module.exports = ({ markdownAST }) => {
  visit(markdownAST, 'link', node => {
    if (
      node.url &&
      !node.url.startsWith('//') &&
      !node.url.startsWith('http')
    ) {
      node.url = node.url.replace(/^(.*)\.md$/, (match, path) => {
        return `/${path}/`;
      })
    }
  });

  return markdownAST;
};
```

See the complete example here: https://github.com/stephane-klein/gatsby-remark-convert-linker-from-md-to-html-example